# Is there a way to temporarily ignore permissions on SharePoint Online for the purposes of a powershell script?

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, admin

I have a tenant admin account for a SharePoint online tenant.  I am tasked with looking at all the sites on the tenant and all the SharePoint groups on each site.  Getting a list of sites is easy using PNP libraries (Get-PnPTenantSite).  My next step is to loop through each site and get all the security groups associated with each site - also easy using Get-PnPGroup commandlet.

The problem I'm running into is that my tenant admin is not added to some sites - not Site Admin, Not Site Owner, not even Site Reader - and so when my script executes against one of these sites, I'm getting a 403 Forbidden when asking for the groups on the site.  Yes, I could avoid this by just adding my tenant admin as an owner on every single site in the tenant, and could probably even do this using a fairly simple powershell script.

However, my question is, why is this necessary?  Shouldn't I be able to just run a script with some kind of "tenant admin super-read-permissions" or something that will just temporarily give me all access to everything without having to go through the middle step of adding myself everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the needs of your business with SharePoint, it may seem like an unnecessary or extra layer of security. After all, why not allow an administrator to access all the things?

The answer lies in the fact that SharePoint security is designed to allow separation of roles. These roles may not necessarily match exactly how responsibilities are defined in your company.

From Microsoft:

> Global Administrators and SharePoint Administrators don't have
> automatic access to all sites and each user's OneDrive, but they can
> give themselves access to any site or OneDrive.

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/sharepoint-admin-role

Tenant admins have several responsibilities:

- Create sites
- Delete sites
- Manage sharing settings at the organization level
- Add and remove site admins
- Manage site storage limits

To perform these responsibilities, very little access to the actual sites and their content is required.

Management of access to a site collection and its content is the responsibility of the site collection administrator and site owners.

It sounds like in your company, you wear both hats. You might be creating and deleting sites, and also getting involved in access control or auditing at the site collection level. In these cases, you must use the privilege of the tenant admin (e.g., add and remove site admins) to grant yourself the site collection privileges required to access the information you need.

I recommend not granting yourself these privileges forever. It is helpful to consider that having constant administrative access to all sites is undesirable for a few reasons. For instance:

- Search is supposed to be filtered to content that is relevant to the user. If the user is an admin with access to all content, search will not be filtered in a useful way.
- While an administrator may certainly grant themselves access to a site, some collaborators would prefer that their content remain private to their team until or unless they require technical support.

All of this addresses the "why" part of your question. As for the technical question, there is currently no "tenant admin super-read-permissions" role that you can use for the data you want to collect.